# NUM Error in Excel Using Index Function

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing, dynamic

I am using the INDEX function to dynamically sort a list of golf scores. I am receiving a #NUM error for a few players, but my formula is working for others. I'm baffled and do not know what is causing the error for some but not all. Can anyone see what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: If you look, it is the second person with the score and beyond which causes the problem, this suggests it lies with the parameter passed to SMALL.

Comment: @RobAnthony hmmm do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: I'm thinking you might need to use VBA because, what you normally do, is use the row number to count the nth smallest number BUT you are starting again with each new score.

Comment: I just figured it out. I'm so silly. I am using an array formula which has to be entered using CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I'm so silly. I am using an array formula which has to be entered using CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I've done that and I'm still getting #N/A when the golfer's scores are zero. Is yours working?

Comment: Yes, ctrl, shift, enter for the first person, and then you have to copy formulas down again. This worked for me.